# moving a player around a 2d monopoly game array

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating the player class for a monopoly board game.  I am not exactly sure how to make the player move around the board and then store that players position.  I have created an array with 40 places using

```
    BoardSquare[] square = new BoardSquare[40];
```

and i have created two die using

```
    diceOne=1+(int)(Math.random()*6);
    diceTwo=1+(int)(Math.random()*6);

    roll=diceOne+diceTwo;
```

this is the code for my player class so far

```
class Player
{
private String name;
private String token;
private int location;
private int balance;

public Player()

{
        name = "";
        token = "";
        location = 0;
        balance = 1500;
        player = (name+token+location+balance);

} 


public Player(String name, String token, int location, int balance)

{
        this.name = name;
        this.token = token;
        this.location = location;
        this.balance = balance;
}
```

i realize i need to initialize a player to zero and then add the value of the rolled die to give the plahyer a position on the board.  However, i am really not sure what happens when space runs out, how to properly develop the for loop, etc.  I have looked at some examples but i am not really sure how to properly develop the logic for a board game.  Any suggestions about board game development that are outside of the scope of this question are most welcome.  thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [modulo operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) to wrap positions around, e.g.:

```
int newPosition = (oldPosition + diceRoll) % 40;
```

As for passing Go you have many options. It's simplest if you define Go as index 0. You can compute the position before modulo 40 and check if its greater than 40 (meaning its about to wrap around). You can also check to see if the new position is less than the old position (which works presuming you can never have a dice roll >= 40).

Comment: Ok that sounds good.  But i'm not really sure how to initialize the player position in the array from the first roll.

Comment: Monopoly rules state that all players start out on Go. Define Go as index 0 and then, just as the rules say, start everybody off at 0 (as it appears you are already doing).

Answer (score 0):

Just before updating the new position of the player ,do the following check:

```
if(position>40)
{
position=position-40
}
```

update the changed position with the specifics of money